# Angular get object property by custom key

Tags: angularjs, object, expression

I've got an object going

```
$scope.myObj = [{"customid":25,"value":"value 1"},{"customid":54,"value":"value 2"}];
```

On the other hand I have a reference to the Id like

```
$scope.selectedCustomId = 24;
```

In an angular expression I would simply like to go

```
{{ myObj[{"customid":selectedCustomId}].value }}
```

However this doesn't work. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: `$scope.myObj` is an array, also arguably still an object. So the first key to be use is the array index. Creating a custom method seem a good way to go, and call it from your template as `{{getItem(selectedCustomId)}}` and `$scope.getItem()` can loop over the array and return the right object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, it is a question about how to [find an object in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find%20object%20array%20javascript) in javascript.

Comment: Thanks @GillesC I used that in combination with `myObj.filter(function(a){ return a.id == typeId })[0]` and it worked a treat. Was just hoping I could find an expression-only solution but this works

Answer (score 1):

Try this using filter:

```
.filter("filterCustomId", function() {
    return function(filterCustomItem, param) {
        var customItem = {};

        angular.forEach(myObj, function(item, j) {
            if(filterCustomItem == item.customid){
                customItem = item;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return customItem.value;
    };
});
```

In html:

```
{{myObj | filterCustomId : selectedCustomId}}
```